# Some vimrc settings don't work unless I source vimrc myself

Tags: vim

I have this specific setting to stop auto commenting after new line.

```
" stop auto commenting
set formatoptions-=r formatoptions-=c formatoptions-=o
```

I have to :so vimrc to make it work

This problem doesn't seem to be happening with other settings as far as I know
And for plugins, I don't have that much, I thought maybe one of them is doing this problem

```
Plug 'preservim/nerdcommenter'

Plug 'itchyny/lightline.vim'

Plug 'tpope/vim-fugitive'
Plug 'preservim/nerdtree'
Plug 'farmergreg/vim-lastplace'
Plug 'vimwiki/vimwiki'
Plug 'junegunn/fzf'

Plug 'morhetz/gruvbox'
```

Comment: Comment out your plugins and you'll know whether one of them is causing the problem. If yes, reactivate half of them etc. until you find the culprit.

Comment: It looks like a classic case of ftplugins overiding those options.

Comment: try `:verbose set formatoptions?` to find the ftplugin causing this.

Comment: vim questions should be asked on https://vi.stackexchange.com/ This is not a programming question.

Answer (score 3):

The settings you put in your `vimrc` are to be considered as a baseline, the kind that takes effect when you do `$ vim xyz` and nothing built-in or added by you tries to override it.

Assuming you have something like:

```
filetype plugin indent on
```

in your `vimrc` (some plugin managers do it on your behalf), ftplugins, first-party or third-party, *will* set their own `formatoptions` when a file with the corresponding filetype is edited. This is perfectly normal and expected. That is Vim's canonical way of doing that kind of things. The *proper* way to set options the way *you* like for a given filetype is thus to do it at the filetype level, just like Vim.

In this case, you should create the following directory structure if it doesn't exist already:

```
~/.vim/after/ftplugin/
```

and set your options in:

```
~/.vim/after/ftplugin/vim.vim
```

as follows:

```
setlocal formatoptions-=r formatoptions-=c formatoptions-=o
```

Note the use of `:help :setlocal` instead of `:help :set`, to keep the value from leaking outside of the buffer in which it is set.

---

Editing Vim's system-wide runtime files is a very bad idea. Don't.